# Ajax extension in .NET 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, .net-2.0

Question: If I want to use ajax extension with Visual Studio 2005, i have to download ajax extensions.

Now here's my question: 
Do I need to do this only for development, or do I also need to install something on the production server if I make my project use ajax extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install it on the production server as well.  This will place the appropriate dll's in the GAC.

You may be able to include those dll's in you local bin, and deploy those with your application.  The easiest way to do this is to mark the references to the AJAX Extensions dll's as CopyLocal = true.  This should be available as a property of the reference in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the ajax dll on the server you deploy to, or you will get an error saying it could not load the library.

The AjaxControlToolkit.dll file should ideally be in the bin folder of your server, otherwise you get an error such as:

Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30512.17815, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f31c0f84b6d53e' or one of its dependencies.